# Arrow with 90 degree angle

Tags: tikz-arrows

I would like to create a 90-degree angle with Tikz and I have two related questions:

**Attempt**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=north west]
\begin{scope}[xshift = 0cm, yshift = -3.5cm]
   \draw[-->] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**Question(s)**

I noticed that `[-->]` was not the proper way to draw an arrow. How do I draw an arrow with a 90-degree angle in Tikz? Furthermore, I was wondering why the arrow isn't drawn within the scope?

Comment: replace `-->` by `->` and you'll get the arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested @Ignasi and after removing all unnecessary code (`scope`, `xshift` and `yshift` in your code fragment doing nothing) for showing your arrow:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[->] (0,0) -| (2,2); % <---
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]